# how to get data in dict from list and store back in dict form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Here is the dictionary form

```
abc = {
    'if1': {'name': 'data', 'date': '80980'}, 
    'if2': {'name': 'data_1', 'date': '9886878'},
    'if3': {'name': 'data', 'date': '0987667'}, 
    'if4': {'name': 'data__5', 'date': '0987667'},
    'if5': {'date': '0987667'}
}
```

and I am trying to apply a filter using the NAME when I give input filter in the form of a list

`list_item = ['data','data_1']`

it should give me the output dates as follows

```
{ 
  data:['80980', '0987667'],
  data_1:['9886878']
}
```

please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the resulting dictionary we create a `defaultdict` with an empty list as the default value. Then we loop over all values of 'abc' and check if we have an entry with the key `'name'` and the corresponding value is in `list_items`. If this is the case we can use the name as a key for the resulting dictionary and append the value of the element with the key `'date`'.

```
abc = {
    'if1': {'name': 'data', 'date': '80980'},
    'if2': {'name': 'data_1', 'date': '9886878'},
    'if3': {'name': 'data', 'date': '0987667'},
    'if4': {'name': 'data__5', 'date': '0987667'},
    'if5': {'date': '0987667'}
}

list_item = ['data','data_1']

import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in abc.values():
    if item.get('name', None) in list_item:
        result[item['name']].append(item['date'])
print(result)
```

An other approach is looping over the values in 'list_item'.

```
result = {}
for key in list_item:
    result[key] = [item['date'] for item in abc.values() if item.get('name', None) == key]
print(result)
```

Using a dictionary comprehension you can transform the last solution into a one-liner (but I prefer a more readable style):

```
result = {key:[item['date'] for item in abc.values() if item.get('name', None) == key] for key in list_item}
```

Answer (score 0):

This dict is so complex you can't just filter it, you have to convert it to something more useful.

```
abc= {  'if1':{'name':'data','date':'80980'}, 'if2':{'name':'data_1','date':'9886878'}, 'if3':{'name':'data','date':'0987667'}, 'if4':{'name':'data__5','date':'0987667'}}
```

[The dictionary was made wrongly, I assumed 2nd `if4` is a typo and I deleted it when I copied the text.]

First, let's flatten it by removing the inside dictionary, making `date` our dict's value:

```
formatted1 = {(key, subdict['name']): subdict['date'] for key, subdict in abc.items() if 'name' in subdict}
```

I kept the original key as part of the new key because otherwise we'd overwrite our `data` entry.

Our new dict looks like that:

```
{('if1', 'data'): '80980', ('if2', 'data_1'): '9886878', ('if3', 'data'): '0987667', ('if4', 'data__5'): '0987667'}
```

Now it's easier to work with. Let's do a simple loop to format it further:

```
formatted2 = {}
for (_, key), value in formatted1.items(): # we'll be skipping first part of the key, hence I didn't give it a meaningful name
    elem = formatted2.get(key, [])
    elem.append(value)
    formatted2[key] = elem
```

Our even newer dict looks now like that:

```
{'data': ['80980', '0987667'], 'data_1': ['9886878'], 'data__5': ['0987667']}
```

---

**And now it's finally in a form we can easily filter!**

```
list_item = ['data','data_1']
result = {k: formatted2[k] for k in formatted2 if k in list_item}
```

Result:

```
{'data': ['80980', '0987667'], 'data_1': ['9886878']}
```

Comment: thank you so much but some times there is no keyword called NAME in dict it has to skip those as well

Comment: Added ` if 'name' in subdict` to first formatting to get only those which have `name`. Please try this now.

Comment: "This dict is so complex you can't just filter it" - I disagree.

Comment: @Matthias there should've been "easily". ;) I changed the text just before posting, at the final step I mentioned "form we can easily filter". Of course we can filter everything. If it wasn't filterable at all, no conversion would help.